# Angular - Direction attribute usable in view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My view looks like this:

```
<li game="12.99">Game2 <span ng-show="(price > 12.99)">test</span></li>
```

Is there any way to access price (12.99) in the **view**, so my code would look like:

```
<li game="12.99">Game2 <span ng-show="(price > self.price)">test</span></li>
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ng-init](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) to create a $scope property:

```
<li ng-init="price=12.99" game="{{price}}">Game2 <span ng-show="price > 12.99">test</span></li>
```

Comment: Yes, but I'll have several directives, so I don't global (or controller) scope is an option.